# Why can't I read other files on Jetty, besides root.war?

Tags: configuration, cgi, jetty

I have root.war and cgi-bin-perl directory under Jetty's webapps directory. I am able to run the UI code in root.war, but I am not able to read cgi files and xml files under cgi-bin-perl directory, e.g. hello.cgi, plugin.xml. It returns the error "cannot be found". Here is my etc/webdefault.xml file. What do I miss?

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PerlCGI</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CGI</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>commandPrefix</param-name>
         <param-value>/usr/bin/perl</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cgibinResourceBase</param-name>
        <param-value>/opt/jetty/webapps/cgi-bin-perl</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PerlCGI</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.pl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your servlet mapping means that only patterns that end in pl will be executed by the servlet....there is nothing here that will serve out other files under that url.

If you want access to those files then you should setup a default servlet under that url space and let it serve out those files.  By default jetty will not let you download whatever files you like, you have to configure it to do that!